# Integrating Bulma Sass with Preact

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, bulma, preact

currently I am playing around with Preact's default project and I want to integrate with Bulma Sass framework to build an UI.

I have searched but have not found a correct way in my case. I don't want to use Typescript or Bulma Components for Preact. Just want to use Bulma on HTML level.

Any suggestions or documentation on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have solved it as :

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader@7.3.1
npm install bulma
```

By the help of these documentations : [Using CSS preprocessors](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli#sass) & [Bulma CSS with React](https://medium.com/@thexap/how-to-setup-bulma-css-framework-with-react-under-5-minutes-a3d8c2c33a87)

**Note : sass-loader@8.0.0 has compatibility issue with Preact**